# Express : Custom node_module on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, poet

I'm using the Poet module in an Express app. Poet don't support Expresss 4 yet, but a patch exist, a change in the module code.

I applied that patch, and my app is working locally.

But Heroku load the original version of the package, without patch.

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419374/express-custom-module-not-loading-on-heroku?rq=1), I run

```
heroku run bash
cat my-file
```

It confirmed that heroku is working with the wrong version of the module.

How can I apply the change to my heroku app ?

Answer (score 1):

Create your npm own module, at some github repo, with the path, and use:

```
 npm install --from-git git@server:project
```

I gues this way it should work :3

Comment: Can't make it work, pb at npm install ("no compatible version found"...) I will try another way, thanks anyway :)